# Why does my IF statement returns error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I am using this expression to either produce Yes or No in RDLC column, based on other columns but it gives error. Why ?

```
=IIF(Fields!ApprovalsDraftsmanApproval.Value= 0 
or Fields!ApprovalsInspectorApproval.Value= 0 
or Fields!ApprovalsPatwariApproval.Value=0, "No", "False")
```

Update:

LOGIC: See I have 10 columns in RDLC report, having 3 BIT type columns, now I took last column to decide IF any of 3 BIT columns has FALSE value then choose Yes, else NO in each row

Comment: what error????? Whats your logic?

Comment: @Imad: See I have 10 columns in RDLC report, having 3 BIT type columns, now I took last column to decide IF any of 3 BIT columns has FALSE value then choose Yes, else NO in each row

Comment: Check for possibility of null/dbnull value in any of these columns

Comment: you are using vb or c#

Comment: @haraman not sir, not NULL value

Comment: @Imad: C#.net, with asp.net

Comment: AFAIK, even though your web application is in C#, you can't do SSRS expressions in C#

Answer (score 3):

IIF is a VB specific statement, it doesn't exist in C#. Instead use "?" tenary operator. See below:

```
var result = Fields!ApprovalsDraftsmanApproval.Value == 0 ||
Fields!ApprovalsInspectorApproval.Value == 0 ||
Fields!ApprovalsPatwariApproval.Value == 0 ? "No" : "False";
```

EDIT

You also need to know - In C# there is a difference between "=" and "==". "=" is used to assign a value, while "==" is used to compare values. So You can't compare values in C# using "=" operator.

Comment: C#.net, with asp.net bro

Comment: C# is C# no mather if it's a desktop, web or anything else.

Comment: and I use IFF in C# too but not working in this case, so it is some other problem not related to VB or C# syntax

Comment: and I tried your answer but not working, gives error in syntax

Comment: plus == can not be used in RDLC expression

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing to this problem many many times... my solution is breakdown

```
if then
else
end if
```

Or I played a trick with Val()

```
=IIF(val(Fields!ApprovalsDraftsmanApproval.Value)= 0 
or val(Fields!ApprovalsInspectorApproval.Value)= 0 
or val(Fields!ApprovalsPatwariApproval.Value)=0, "No", "False")
```

It helps me all the times